# I keep getting a timeout error for an element even though it prints out the text of that element

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to Selenium and my main goal is to scrape the video game stats I earned for each game I played, here is the code I have so far:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    url = "https://destinytracker.com/destiny-2/profile/psn/4611686018440125811/matches?mode=crucible"
    driver.get(url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    ignored_exceptions=(NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException)
    crucible_content = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.trn-gamereport-list.trn-gamereport-list--compact")))
    game_reports = crucible_content.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "trn-gamereport-list__group")
    for game_report in game_reports:
        group_entry = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "trn-gamereport-list__group-entries")))
        win_match = group_entry.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"trn-match-row--outcome-win")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", win_match[0])
        lose_match = group_entry.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "trn-match-row--outcome-loss")
        for win_element in win_match:
            
            #try:
                #sleep(10)
                #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", win_element)
                
            win_left = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "trn-match-row__section--left")))
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", win_left)
            print("reached here")
            date_time = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='info']")))
            date_time = date_time.text
            date_time = date_time.split(",")
            date_time = date_time[0]
            match_roster = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"match-rosters")))
            team_alpha = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.match-roster.alpha")))
            team_bravo = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.match-roster.bravo")))
            bravo_match_roster_entries = team_bravo.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "roster-entries")
            alpha_match_roster_entries = team_alpha.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"roster-entries")
            name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "router-link-active")))
            entry_bravo = bravo_match_roster_entries.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"entry")
            entry_alpha = alpha_match_roster_entries.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"entry")
            print(date_time)
```

I want to loop over each win I have and collect the stats from that game(along with the time.) I get this result:

```
reached here
7/12/2023
reached here
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/victoruduma/Documents/python web scraping part 2 .py", line 121, in <module>
    crucible_dataset()
  File "/Users/victoruduma/Documents/python web scraping part 2 .py", line 55, in crucible_dataset
    date_time = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='info']")))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

the problem I'm having is that even though I get that error, it still prints out the date. I have been stuck on this problem for the past week, even with the help of CHATGPTA. any help would be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you loop over the `win_match` and `click` on `win_left`, you should **close** the pop-up window that appears on the click before the next loop on the `win_match`

```py
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.close"))).click()
```

Here's how:

```py
from time import sleep
from selenium.common import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


driver = Chrome()
url = "https://destinytracker.com/destiny-2/profile/psn/4611686018440125811/matches?mode=crucible"
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

crucible_content = wait.until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.trn-gamereport-list.trn-gamereport-list--compact")))
game_reports = crucible_content.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "trn-gamereport-list__group")

for game_report in game_reports:
    group_entry = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "trn-gamereport-list__group-entries")))
    win_match = group_entry.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.trn-match-row--outcome-win")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", win_match[0])
    lose_match = group_entry.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.trn-match-row--outcome-loss")
    for win_element in win_match:

        try:
            win_left = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.trn-match-row__section--left")))
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", win_left)
            print("reached here")
            date_time = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='info']")))
            date_time = date_time.text.split(",")[0]
            match_roster = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "match-rosters")))
            team_alpha = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.match-roster.alpha")))
            team_bravo = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.match-roster.bravo")))
            bravo_match_roster_entries = team_bravo.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "roster-entries")
            alpha_match_roster_entries = team_alpha.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "roster-entries")
            name = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "router-link-active")))
            entry_bravo = bravo_match_roster_entries.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "entry")
            entry_alpha = alpha_match_roster_entries.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "entry")
            print(date_time)
            wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.close"))).click()
            sleep(1)
        except TimeoutException:
            pass
```

output:

```
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
reached here
7/13/2023
```

Comment: Thank you! If I wanted to add more code  after the print(date_time) line, should I write the code after the pop up window is closed or write the remaining code I wanted to do and then close the popup window

Comment: if the extra code you want to write is related to the contents on the popup window then you should write it before closing it otherwise you can write after closing.

Comment: Hello @Ajeet Verma I was wondering if you could help me with another selenium question?